# Getting selected elements properties in forge viewer when more then one model loaded

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have have a viewer app with 8 models loaded

I have a plugin looking for the `"AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT"` event

```
this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, this.onSelectionBinded);
```

I need to be able to get access to the selected elements properties

```
this.viewer.getProperties(_dbId, (result) => { })
```

but it seams the viewer is only looking at the last loaded model not all of them. 
do i have to `load/switch` to the other models ? and if so how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewer.model` is always pointed to the first loaded model with my experience. If you want to access other loaded models, you can obtain them via calling `viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels()`. Afterward, call Viewer properties APIs in this way:

```
var allModels = viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels();
var model = allModels[1];
model.getProperties( dbId, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback );
```

Besides, you can obtain the model instance in the function argument `event` of your `onSelectionBinded` callback. So, your `onSelectionBinded` can be modified to this based on the above logic:

```
this.onSelectionBinded = function( event ) {
    var selSet = event.selections;
    var firstSel = selSet[0];

    var model = firstSel.model;
    var dbIds = firstSel.dbIdArray;
    var firstDbId = dbIds[0];

    model.getProperties( firstDbId, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback );
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late...

Another way to get properties for multi-model, is to use the aggregated method.

```
var DBids = viewer.impl.selector.getAggregateSelection();
```

I have a blog post and sample website that goes through the details:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/highlighting-clashes-multi-model[image]