# How can I use Autodesk Forge APIs to extract metadata from an uploaded AutoCAD file into a web aplication?

Tags: api, autodesk-forge, autocad, autodesk

I want to upload a dwg file and extract the information of all the plane information (like surface, areas, attributes, tags, etc).

How can I do? Which API I should use to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By Model Derivative API of Forge, some general data of the model objects will be extracted. By [GET:Properties endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/), or after loading model in Forge Viewer, some functions such as [viewer.getProperties ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371027/getting-selected-elements-properties-in-forge-viewer-when-more-then-one-model-lo) will return the data as properties.

if the data is not available with the properties, you may have to write AutoCAD plugin to extract the information by AutoCAD API yourself. The plugin can be executed by [Forge Design
Automation of AutoCAD](http://By%20Model%20Derivative%20API%20of%20Forge,%20some%20general%20data%20of%20the%20model%20objects%20will%20be%20extracted.%20By%20%5BGET:Properties%20endpoint%5D%5B1%5D,%20or%20after%20loading%20model%20in%20Forge%20Viewer,%20some%20functions%20such%20as%20%5Bviewer.getProperties%20()%5D%5B2%5D%20will%20return%20the%20data%20as%20properties.%20%20if%20the%20data%20is%20not%20available%20with%20the%20properties,%20you%20may%20have%20to%20write%20AutoCAD%20plugin%20to%20extract%20the%20information%20by%20AutoCAD%20API%20yourself.%20The%20plugin%20can%20be%20executed%20by%20%5BForge%20Design%20%20Automation%20of%20AutoCAD%5D%5B3%5D%20if%20you%20need%20to%20build%20a%20cloud%20solution%20without%20running%20the%20plugin%20on%20local%20AutoCAD.%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/%20%20%20%5B2%5D:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371027/getting-selected-elements-properties-in-forge-viewer-when-more-then-one-model-lo%20%20%20%5B3%5D:%20https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/autocad/) if you need to build a cloud solution without running the plugin on local AutoCAD.